# Java Logging messages following a custom regex pattern

Tags: java.util.logging

I have various modules logging information using various levels. I would like to implement a controller that would log the information only if the message follows certain pattern.

For example -
Module A
logger.info("log this message - A");

Module B
logger.info("log this message - B");

Module C
logger.info("don't log this message - C");

I cannot make changes to A and B to change their level as the number of modules talking to each other is huge.

I would like to have a logging.properties that would log all messages not having "don't log this messages*" pattern.

Can you assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no regex filter included with the logging package in the JDK.  However, you can create your own [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) to throw out messages that match your regex then install it on the handler you want to filter.  If you want to install a custom filter on a specific logger then you have to use the [config](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) property to programmatically install the filter.